# How to run nightmare app in headless mode?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I have a web scraper which uses the the nightmare browser automation library. Everytime I would run my nodejs app it opens up a browser window and loads the page I am trying to scrape. But I want to run it completely in the console without any windows popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you are going to get is just keeping the window hidden. To do this, instantiate your Nightmare as such:

`var nm = new Nightmare({show: false})`

Answer (score 1):

I would say "don't". Use Cheerio instead, it's built for headless HTML scraping

Comment: can it simulate a browser instance?